# Dependency Injection with Weld/CDI on Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, cdi, jboss-weld

Is it possible to use dependency injection with the reference implementation of CDI ([Weld](http://seamframework.org/Weld)) on Android?

If yes ( as Weld seems to need java 1.5, there should be no real obstacles) - are there any examples/resources?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. Weld is quite resource consuming, so you certainly don't want to put it on a device with limited memory. You might wan to try [roboguice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/) if you need a DI framework for Android.

Comment: So it would be rather a "strategic" decision and technically possible? Thanks for the roboguice tip, will be checking the astroboy example out...

Comment: When I last used Weld it needed a couple hundred megabytes to boot. I'm sure it's optimized by now, but still its a _server_ framework. If that is a research project, you might be able to get it work with (heavy, I guess) modifications, but it's hardly practical.

Comment: It was rather a question of using same frameworks on different platforms (as I find having to derive from RoboActivity kinda invasive). But your point is perfectly valid. Thanks

Comment: Here's a recent post with some other options: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/08/26/clean-code-with-android/

Comment: Maybe Apache OpenWebBeans handles resources better.

Answer (score 2):

Since this was the first thing I was missing on Android, I created it as the core feature of the BARACUS Application framework for Android 4+ Applications.

In order not to have an Annotation-based or code generation based overloaded system, it leverages dependency injection by type, [therefore you simply can register an interface plus implementation](http://baracusframework.blogspot.de/2014/08/baracus-from-scratch-part-9-using.html) (useful when you want to write android-aware testable components) or plain java class in the context bootstrap phase.

Also, [it allows to have a Java EE styled bean and a spring styled context lifecycle](http://baracusframework.blogspot.de/2013/10/baracus-from-scratch-part-4-ioc-and-di.html).

The stuff is Apache 2 licensed and hosted on github. Feel free to reuse any code for your purpose.